# Can Jquery be used with v8cgi?

Tags: jquery, serverside-javascript

I would like to use v8cgi for server-side JS, but I can't find anywhere if JQuery would be able to load and run fine in that environment. Has anyone been able to do that? Which of the v8cgi modules are required for JQuery to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a client-side library for DOM manipulation, visual effects, animation and so on. The server side technology supplying data to it is irrelevant. jQuery is not going to care especially what is at the other end of that pipe, and I can't immediately see a use for it at the server-end of the pipe anyway.

Server-side JS is just one option amongst many (Perl, PHP, .Net, Ruby, and many more), and may be a good one for you. It can mean having fewer languages/technologies in the mix, but isn't going to absolve you from having to write and manage separate client and server side components.